# Intel HDgraphics+NVIDIA GT540M+Nouveau working?

Tags: hybrid-graphics

What i´ve learnt is, it´s not a good idea to buy new hardware and use Linux because of less support from the producers.
Machine: lenovoZ570, i7 x64,8GB, 700GB, Nvidia Optimus+Intel, 1366x768, win7+11.10 ubuntu+kubuntu. Until now nvidia isn't installed or used.

Some problems, which may be related to each other:

```
- kubuntu left after update a nonworking package-manager(problems with nouveau)
- Celestia starts and vanishes into nirvana(no 3d?)
- usb-livestick shows non readable screen( pixel don´t fit together)
- partedmagic6.7 has icons which freeze but don´t work
- two grub2, one inactive on the ubuntu partition and one at MBR really on kubuntu 
  partition
- during kubuntu menu config one point is "science" but despite show hidden it´s not
  to see
```

Since 3 weeks I've been trying to get a running machine and I don't like the fact that is sometimes not booting, gives me black screens and freezing (it is cold enough outside). I know, that my wishes are not standard and I could find a solution by reading several sites for cryptical commands and how to run them on a terminal, but I wanted only a secure and stable runnig machine, not 6 weeks of frustration.

I have learnt that switcheroo doesn't work with optimus, but Bumblebee 3.0 should work.
**Is it a good idea to try this or will it create more problems?**

So, heavy stuff, hope somebody understands my German English and prevents any more frustration on my side. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to split up your questions, the current one is hard to read. If your basic question is about your video card, don't mention printers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Lenovo Ideapad Z570 that is reported to work with the recently released Bumblebee 3.0. If you think your installation is still find, I would follow the installation instructions for Bumblebee 3.0, including the cleanup script that will make sure any other related packages are cleaned up before installation of bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Lenovo Ideapad Z570 that is reported to work with the recently released Bumblebee 3.0. If you think your installation is FUBAR, I would personally back up any data you have in the Linux partition, install again in console mode, then install Bumblebee 3.0.

Comment: After i´ve learnt that FUBAR means totally broken ore or not to be use, thats not. There are problems, but still nearly all is running (could be better). I´ve one own partition for home (both for ubuntu+kubuntu), so personal data are safe, but all installed

Comment: Thanks, after i´ve learnt that FUBAR means totally broken ore or not to be use, thats not. There are problems, but still nearly all is running (could be better). I´ve one own partition for home (both for ubuntu+kubuntu), so personal data are safe, but all installed programs would be gone. I thought trieing now and then with the next longtime-kernel use only what was helpful and functioning. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed bumblebee on both ubuntu and kubuntu now and it works fine. Make use of the bumblebee-wiki, there it is written clearly, what to do!

-First i let a gap after ppa: and this didn´t work. 
-Would like a button, may be at power-management, to really stop or start the discrete card. bbswitch works automatically ok, but **there is in front a little hardwareswitch, isn´t it possible to make it working?**

Celestia starts now but has some graphic problems in ubuntu only. Stellarium works fine.

The hidden menu-item "science" in kubuntu has had empty folders or such with only hidden elements and was because of this not shown, no defect of the graphic card.